# How to pivot postgresql (Amazon RDS) dataset around values to make a histogram?

Tags: postgresql, histogram

I'm using Amazon RDS (Aurora) so don't have access to the crosstab() function. 
My dataset is a count of particular actions per user and looks like:

```
|   uid   | action1 | action2 |
| alice   | 2       | 2       |
| bob     | 1       | 2       |
| charlie | 5       | 0       |
```

How can I pivot this dataset to make a histogram of action counts? So it would look like:

```
# | Action1 | Action2
---------------------
0 |         |    1
1 |   1     |    
2 |   1     |    2
3 |         |    
4 |         |    
5 |   1     |    
6 |         |
```

Here's a SQL fiddle I've been using with the values already entered: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b966/1

Comment: My approach [demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=729eafbd5c554f0b60c9edb53d02a145) but it needs some correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but it is very verbose:

```
WITH nums AS (
SELECT n
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) nums(n)
),

action1_counts as (
  select
    action1,
    count(*) as total
  from test
  group by 1
),

action2_counts as (
  select
    action2,
    count(*) as total
  from test
  group by 1
)

select
  nums.n,
  coalesce(a1.total, 0) as Action1,
  coalesce(a2.total, 0) as Action2
from nums
LEFT join action1_counts a1 on a1.action1 = nums.n
LEFT join action2_counts a2 on a2.action2 = nums.n
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume action is between 0 and 6.

```
select a1.action, a1.action1, nullif(count(t2.action2),0) as action2
from
(  select t.action, nullif(count(t1.action1),0) as action1 
   from
   (select action from generate_series(0,6) g(action)) t
   left join
   test t1
   on t1.action1 = t.action
   group by t.action 
) a1
left join
test t2
on t2.action2 = a1.action
group by a1.action, a1.action1
order by a1.action
```